# IOS8 Register Notificaton not working. Why?

Tags: push-notification, ios8, apple-push-notifications

My app APNS is working well in less then ios8, but in ios8 i am not getting device token, even didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken delegate method is not called. Please advise.

Comment: Show your APNS registering code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had same problem along with my application and refer below link and resolve this

clickable link

[Get Device Token in iOS 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24426090/get-device-token-in-ios-8)

```
#ifdef __IPHONE_8_0
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterUserNotificationSettings:    (UIUserNotificationSettings *)notificationSettings
{
//register to receive notifications
[application registerForRemoteNotifications];
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application handleActionWithIdentifier:(NSString    *)identifier forRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo completionHandler:(void(^)())completionHandler
{
  //handle the actions
 if ([identifier isEqualToString:@"declineAction"]){
}
else if ([identifier isEqualToString:@"answerAction"]){
}
}
#endif
```