# APNS: Failed to validate certificate chain for courier.sandbox.push.apple.com - didRegisterForRemoteNotificationWithDeviceToken is not being called

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

I've implemented apns in my applicaton and it was working till yesterday without any problem. Today suddenly it stopped working and the following method is not being called:

```
-(void) application:(UIApplication) applicaton didRegisterForRemoteNotificationWithDeviceToken:(nonnull NSData *) deviceToken;
```

I didn't find any valid reason. My iOS version is 9.3.2;

In device log I see the following error message:

> Failed to validate certificate chain for
>   courier.sandbox.push.apple.com

I factory reset the device but it didn't work.

Interestingly, the apns works on my other device with same iOS version.

More interestingly, on the same device my another Test Push Application (same code copy and pasted) works fine.

Does anybody have any idea to solve this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Got the same issue starting today with my device, no idea how to solve it.

Comment: Also from today onwards push is not receiving for some valid tokens.

Comment: Looks like the sandbox is not working: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/52224

Comment: check this ... http://stackoverflow.com/a/38456437/4601170

Comment: @TheBronx right there is some issue with sandbox as production is working fine .. .may be due to some updation or regarding some issue

Comment: Yes this is broken for me with the same error. Both iOS9.3.3 and iOS10 devices are non functional:

Comment: It's back online. At least for me!

Comment: Its working now for me.

Answer (score 4):

Similar issue happened to me today as well on 3 test phones, all running iOS 9.3.2. One is an iPhone5 and the other is an iPhone 6.

The following insights may help avoid the problem, until fixed:

1. I saw that the problem only occur when signing the app with a development certificate. On production environment everything seemed to work as expected (both for regular APNS and for VoIP APNS).
2. The problem is reproducible only on one of our apps. A different app, even if signed as development, worked as expected (i.e. didRegisterForRemoteNotificationWithDeviceToken was called by the system).
3. The problem was not reproducible when testing the problematic app on an iOS 8.4.1 phone, both for regular APNS and for VoIP APNS.

Update for July 20, 2016: 
It seems that this was a temporary issue in APNS Sandbox environment, everything went back to normal today.

Comment: Any hints on what might be the difference between the app not working and the working one?

Comment: The only major difference I can spot is that the non working app is currently on iTunes connect while the working one is not.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that, it was a problem of apple push notification sandbox server. Today it's working.