# in APNS, not able to get device token in any device except iPhone 4

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, apple-push-notifications

In APNS, It's not able to get device token in any device except `iPhone 4` and `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken` not executed - Push Notification.

Comment: Did you implement? `- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError *)error`. May be you have have error and this helps you to get description of it.

Comment: @alzert me too facing the same issue from today morning.i am using xcode 7.3.1 and iOS 9.3.

Comment: this may be problem from apple side .. check this  http://stackoverflow.com/a/38456437/4601170  .. production is working fine

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
if (SYSTEM_VERSION_LESS_THAN(@"8.0")) {
    [application registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:  (UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound)];
} else {
    UIUserNotificationSettings *settings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge|UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound|UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert) categories:nil];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it in App delegate DidFinishLaunchingWithOption :
iphone 4 runs on iOS7 only.

```
 if ([application respondsToSelector:@selector(registerUserNotificationSettings:)])
    {
        UIUserNotificationType userNotificationTypes = (UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge | UIUserNotificationTypeSound);
        UIUserNotificationSettings *settings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:userNotificationTypes categories:nil];
        [application registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];  
    }
    else
    {
        // Register for Push Notifications, if running iOS version < 8
        [application registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound)];

    }
```