# Registering for Push Notifications does not get any response

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

I have an app with support for Push Notifications under development for couple of months now. Push Notifications worked just fine until yesterday.

Now the application does not get any callbacks for registering for APNS. `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken` nor `didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError` in the `AppDelegate` is called. Why I don't get any AppDelegate callback when registering for PN?

Registration is properly called:

```
let settings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: [.Alert, .Badge, .Sound], categories: nil)
UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerForRemoteNotifications()
```

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/38456437/4601170

Comment: Check provision profiles,certificates which you have been created is expired ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is not your fault. There is some issue in APNS as on **19 July, 2016**.
For reference check this
[didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken not called in ios8, but didRegister...Settings is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28128490/didregisterforremotenotificationswithdevicetoken-not-called-in-ios8-but-didregi/38454917#38454917)

Once APNS start working , you will start receiving device token and work with push.

Comment: Apple has fixed the issue, it's working now.

Comment: Thanks @MartinKoles :)