# Remote notification device token is not received

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

I'm having a valid Code Signing and `Provisioning profile` are installed. But while I'm run in my device the function **didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken** is not called even **didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError**. Day before it was working fine and notifications received perfectly. It was happened to all my project which are all working fine past days. Please guide me, what I need to do resolve this. Thank you.

Comment: Are you using proper bundle id.

Comment: Same problem. https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/155239#155239

Comment: Yes, that's why receiving a notification in past days

Comment: Possible duplicate of [didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken not called in ios8, but didRegister...Settings is](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28128490/didregisterforremotenotificationswithdevicetoken-not-called-in-ios8-but-didregi)