# didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken no longer being called?

Tags: ios, swift, apple-push-notifications

My app has push notifications enabled, and up until today they were working properly. From setting breakpoints I've realized that the issue is that `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken` is no longer being called. This is confusing to me as my notifications code hasn't change since when it was working (yesterday). Here is what my `AppDelegate` looks like:

```
 import UserNotifications

 func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    ...

    registerForPushNotifications()

    return true
}

func registerForPushNotifications() {
  UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
    .requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound, .badge]) {
      [weak self] granted, error in

      print("Permission granted: \(granted)")
      guard granted else { return }
      self?.getNotificationSettings()
    }
}

func getNotificationSettings() {
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().getNotificationSettings { settings in
        print("Notification settings: \(settings)")
        guard settings.authorizationStatus == .authorized else { return }
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
        }
    }
}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
    let tokenParts = deviceToken.map { data in String(format: "%02.2hhx", data) }
    let token = tokenParts.joined()
    print("Device Token: \(token)")
    global_device_token = token
}
```

The call to `UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()` in `getNotificationSettings` does get run however.

Comment: Is it possible that your APNS certificate expired? If you didn't change your code at all, that might be an option.

Comment: I would remove the `guard settings.authorizationStatus == ...` check - You can always register for remote notifications.  If you don't have permission to show them then nothing will be shown.

Comment: checkout this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59156989/3278326

Comment: @drsanger73 Can you please specify which device / iOS version you are using?

Comment: @ClaudioRedi the certificate hasn't expired yet

Comment: @JarvisTheAvenger Disconnecting from Wifi didn't help. I'm testing this on an iPhone 8 running iOS 13.4, and an iPhone 8 Plus running some version of iOS 13 (unable to check)

Comment: @drsanger73 Can you please try deleting an app and reinstalling it?

Comment: @drsanger73 also check if your `didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError` method is getting called if not `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken `

Comment: @JarvisTheAvenger I tried deleting and installing, still didn't work. However, restarting my phone did work, and `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken` is being called now. I suppose the question is why wasn't it working in the first place?

Comment: Scratch that, `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken` is being called but notification banners aren't appearing when my server sends them.